# It is possible to setup VS Code for this particular project?

Tags: reactjs, web, visual-studio-code

I am currently working with unusual project setup and want to configure VS Code but struggling with achieving this:

1. We have few "src" folders in our project. Is it possible to mark "src" folder as "Resource folder" (option available in IntelliJ) in VS Code? Therefore writing absolute paths related to closest src folder? Right now CMD+click on this type of "absolute path" does not work for me :(
2. JSX specific question. Is it possible to prevent default VS Code formatter from adding additional space before self-closing JSX tag?

Thanks guys!